# DropBox SDK error iOS: unable to link; app isn't registered for correct URL scheme

Tags: ios7, dropbox-api

I am trying to use drop box sdk in my app.

I have followed all the instructions mentioned on their website.
I have initialised DBSession

```
DBSession* dbSession = [[DBSession alloc] initWithAppKey:@"vbhebz1vsjr56dc" appSecret:@"secret" root:kDBRootDropbox];
```

Also added the url schemes by prefixing db- to the Key"vbhebz1vsjr56dd"

But I always get this error--

> [ERROR] DropboxSDK: unable to link; app isn't registered for correct URL scheme (db-vbhebz1vsjr56dc)

[image]

Have gone through other post which have said appending db solves the problem.
but it just isnt working in my case.
Strangely it seemed to work before I had uploaded it on the AppStore.

Comment: Show you Info.plist - at least the URL section. BTW - this is a runtime error, not a linking error.

Comment: That looks like the right URL scheme. Are you still getting the error? Are you sure you've rebuilt and installed the app with this updated plist included?

Comment: I resolved it by adding the URL scheme in the URL Types section rather  than the Custom iOS Target properties section.

Answer (score 0):

@rmaddy's comment is likely the right clue here. This error means you haven't registered for the callback URL (`db-<APP_KEY>`). See https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/sdks/ios, specifically the section "Creating a URL scheme".